# When can I start using a Framework (Laravel)?

Tags: php, frameworks, laravel

I want to start by saying that I searched a lot for this exact question, but none of them satisfied my needs.

I program Php, MySQL, HTML, CSS and Javascript the 'old way', using just a text editor and building every website from scratch. I built websites from the most simple to an-almost e-commerce just by coding every piece of the application. The most advance thing I did was using some simple classes, like a database wrapper, singleton, and for the rest I always used functions.

Now, recently I signed up for a website where there are courses ( I won't say its name because I don't know if I'm allowed ) and I followed one about Laravel 3 ( I know currently its version is 4.x ), and I must admit I fell in love with it. I like it very much and I want to start using it but I'm afraid that doing so will 'dumb' me.

What I mean is that Laravel has a lot of helper functions, Eloquent structure and so on, so by using it I won't learn any more the pure Php because for everything you need there is already a built helper function.

To make a very simple example, if you want to join some tables you use `Eloquent` and within literally 3 second you accomplish this. If you want to log a user in, again you have an `Auth` class that does everything for you, even setting sessions.

This is my biggest fear, that I won't learn anything anymore because all you need is already provided, you don't have to think that much anymore.

On the other side, Laravel helps you a lot and it eases your work very much. As much as I want to start digging into it more I can't help but fear its downsides.

- So, do you think I should wait and learn more traditional Php before dive into a Framework?
- When is the right time to start using one?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Look at all the sites you built. Identify redundant elements. Extract them into classes and functions and build your own framework.** This will allow you to build sites faster and build a library. Once you do that, there's no dumbing down. You can choose to use another or not... but you'll have yours too.

*That's what I did. I have my own framework. And it ain't bad!*

There are two types of developers:

- **users** - they can use stuff and get by
- **actual developers** - they can build stuff from scratch and give users tools

*Choose which model fits your needs best.*

- **1st category** goes for quick results, are efficient and get the job done. These guys should use 3rd party frameworks and libraries.
- **2nd category** are artists pushing themselves further with each new piece of code they build. They go for performance over turnaround time, code beauty and functionality vs. just functionality, etc... These guys feel offended by 3rd party frameworks and libraries and always roll their own. Because they can!

**There's another catch.** Some frameworks might have too much fat for your needs. Building more specialized solutions might actually yield way better performance than a one-size-fits-all framework. That's another perspective.

*Bafta mai departe :)*

Comment: I don't agree with the 2 types you mentioned. Creating stuff from scratch is just a crazy approach for any enterprise level applications. Code-reuse is always a great and must-do practice for any real apps. Actual developers will always reuse codes and won't invent the wheel from the beginning. This is why all great PHP developers use frameworks such as Laravel, Yii, Zend, Cake or similars.

Comment: Agree. reinventing the wheel is good for learning purpose, but for production usage it's better to use a framework.